# How to display "No data" message using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

The code looks as following:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="action in actionList">
        <td></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="!actionList.length">
        <td>
            No data.                
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works, but not in way I want because it initially displays "No data" message. I need to display nothing initially and the table with data if actionList.length is not 0. If actionList.length is 0 then display "No data" message, but not as a part of table.

**Update:**

I've added in my controler:

```
$scope.isButtonClicked = false;

$scope.queryResult = function () {
    $scope.isButtonClicked = true;
    $scope.actionList = [];
    $scope.actionsQuery.resetPage();
    appendPage();
};
```

But, "No data." message appears on every click. When there's some data it appears very shortly and disappears and when there's no data, it appears correctly.

Comment: You need to maintain an loading indicator.

Comment: What is loading indicator?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why you confusing? Lot of way of  you can think to solve this.

**Try this simple way**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-show="actionList.length!=0" ng-repeat="action in actionList">
        <td></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td ng-show="actionList.length==0">
            No data.                
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## Update 1:-

- Also you need to check `actionList` is undefined or null
- And You should `$scope.actionList` is a `array`
- You can check the `actionList` is *null or undefined* with [ng-if Statement](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) **(try with ng-if instead of ng-show in the div tag)**

Something like this below way

```
<div ng-show="actionList !='null' && actionList !='undefined'">
 <table>
        <tr ng-show="actionList.length!=0" ng-repeat="action in actionList">
            <td></td>
            ...
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td ng-show="actionList.length==0">
                No data.                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div ng-show="actionList =='null'|| actionList =='undefined'">
 No data. 
</div>
```

### Update 2 :-

**Another simple way to instead of my update 1**

*try this below code.*

```
<table>
    <tr ng-show="actionList!='undefined' && actionList!='null' && actionList.length!=0"  ng-repeat="action in actionList">
        <td></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr >
    <td ng-show="actionList=='undefined' ||actionList=='null' || actionList.length==0 ">
            No data.                
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> **Here you can try with ng-if instead of ng-show**

## Update 3:

> ***I want because it initially displays "No data" message. I need to display nothing initially and the table with data if actionList.length is not 0. If actionList.length is 0 then display "No data" message, but not as a part of table.***

So Simple ...

- Create a new Boolean  Scope variable like a named as `IsButtonClick`
- Globally declare `$scope.IsButtonClick==false`
- Set `$scope.IsButtonClick==true` on your button click event

*Then copy past this below code instead of your html code.*

```
<div ng-show="IsButtonClick">
    <table>
            <tr ng-show="actionList!='undefined' && actionList!='null' && actionList.length!=0"  ng-repeat="action in actionList">
                <td></td>
                ...
            </tr>           
        </table>
</div>
<div ng-show="IsButtonClick"> <span ng-show="actionList=='undefined' ||actionList=='null' || actionList.length==0 "> No data.</span>  </div>
```

## Update 4 :

> **But, "No data." message appears on every click. When there's some data it appears very shortly and disappears and when there's no data, it appears correctly**

try this way

```
$scope.queryResult = function () { 
        $scope.isButtonClicked = false;      
        $scope.actionList = [];
        $scope.actionsQuery.resetPage();
        appendPage();
        if($scope.actionList.Length==0)
        {
          $scope.isButtonClicked = true;
        }
    };
```

and the html is

```
<div ng-show="IsButtonClick">
        <table>
                <tr ng-show="actionList!='undefined' && actionList!='null' && actionList.length!=0"  ng-repeat="action in actionList">
                    <td></td>
                    ...
                </tr>           
            </table>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="IsButtonClick"> <span ng-hide="actionList !='undefined' || actionList!='null' || actionList.length!=0 "> No data.</span>  </div>
```

Comment: The issue is the table is populating with data when you on click on button on the same page. When you doesn't click button, "No data" will be visible initially, which is not needed.

Comment: So What? You need to  assign the values to `$scope.actionList` on the button click event.  Can you explain properly for what you want ?\

Comment: When I click search button, there will be some results or not. If results exist they are shown in the table, if not the message "No data." is shown. But, the message should be out of table.

Comment: Please see my Update 3

Comment: @tesicg Dude, It's does make sense?

Comment: The behavior is the same, which means "No data." message appears all the time.

Comment: Okay' I gave to lot of updates. please see that and  take the answers like a key....

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
<tr ng-show="!actionList.length">
    <td ng-bind="noData">

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's not working because the style says to display nothing (none).

Comment: [ngBing](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) expect to  get an expression. `"No data"` is not an expression...

Comment: oh sorry silly mistake. u can use a `$scope.noData` variable to check the length property in the controller after getting the data

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div ng-switch="!!actionsList.length">

  <div ng-switch-when="true">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="...">
        <td> ... </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div ng-switch-when="false">
    No data
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't display any data.

Comment: ok edited my answer, to be sure having a boolean. can you retry it ?

Comment: It returns data now, but when there's no data there's no "No data" message.

Comment: It means `$scope.actionsList` have a length... Can you console.log() it ? Maybe initialize it as `[]` at the top of your controller ?